# Ayuda con DISTINCT en Oracle

Tags: oracle

Llevo desde ayer intentando sacar una SELECT en condiciones para el curro. A ver si sois capaces de ayudarme.

Tablas:

### direcciones

```
ID             NUMBER
TIPO_Direccion NUMBER
id_persona     NUMBER
direccion      VARCHAR2(50)
```

### personas

```
id     NUMBER
nombre VARCHAR2(50)
```

El caso es que relaciono las tablas así
    SELECT per.id AS id_persona
    , per.nombre
    , dir.id AS id_direccion
    , dir.tipo_direccion
    , dir.direccion
    FROM personas per
    JOIN direcciones dir ON per.id = dir.id_persona
    ;

El tipo de direccion puede ser:

```
- nacional := 0
- principal := 1
- segunda casa := 2
```

Cada persona puede tener sólo una "nacional" o "principal" y diferentes "segunda casa".

Me piden que aparezca en ése orden y sólo de una persona. El problema es que no consigo hacer funcionar "distinct".

Todo debe ser en una View montada, no me valen funciones aunque pueden ser llamadas.

EDITO:

En principio usé el DISTINCT de esta forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (per.id AS id_persona)
, per.nombre
, dir.id AS id_direccion
, dir.tipo_direccion
, dir.direccion
FROM personas per
JOIN direcciones dir ON per.id = dir.id_persona
ORDER BY dir.tipo_direccion
;
```

Pero me aparecen todas las direcciones posibles de la persona. Es una especie de priorización por el campo tipo_direccion:
Primero, los que tengan el tipo de direccion "nacional" := 0
Segundo, los que lo tengan "principal"                  := 1 
Tercero, los que lo tengan en "segunda casa"            := 2

Y que aparezca solamente una direccion por persona. Si tengo a Bill Gates que sólo me aparezca su direccion en California ya que es la que tiene como tipo de direccion nacional. Y no me aparezcan más direcciones.

Comment: Hola bitelmaniaco. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Puedes mostrar la consulta con `distinct` que intentaste junto a por que no te funciona ? errores? resultado no esperado?  Muestanos un ejemplo de los datos que tienes actualmente y como es el resultado que quieres.Un saludo

Comment: La explicación de los campos no termino de entenderla. Te piden que aparezca en ése orden el qué? Explícanos que hace el programa en cuestión o de que trata, no está nada claro con la explicación que has dado.

Comment: @bitelmaniaco He editado mi respuesta en base tu actualización.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT  id_persona, 
        per.nombre, 
        id_direccion, 
        dir.tipo_direccion, 
        dir.direccion
FROM (  SELECT  per.id AS id_persona, 
                per.nombre, 
                dir.id AS id_direccion, 
                dir.tipo_direccion, 
                dir.direccion,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY per.id ORDER BY dir.tipo_direccion)  AS rn
        FROM personas per
        INNER JOIN direcciones dir 
            ON per.id = dir.id_persona) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
;
```

Comment: Justamente es lo que necesitaba!! Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: @bitelmaniaco, si la respuesta de ha ayudado considera darla por aceptada, es la forma adecuada de agradecer. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente query te saca el resultado completo haciendo un DISTINCT sobre cada persona.

Y mediante ORDER BY te quedará ordenado por el campo que quieras. Ordenado de manera ASC (ascendente) aparecerán primero los 0 (nacional) y al final los 2 (segunda casa).

PARTITION BY sirve para indicar que sólamente quieres 1 registro por cada persona en este caso.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT DIRECCIONES.ID_PERSONA,
DIRECCIONES.ID,
DIRECCIONES.TIPO_DIRECCION OVER (PARTITION BY DIRECCIONES.ID_PERSONA),
DIRECCIONES.DIRECCION
FROM
DIRECCIONES,
PERSONAS
WHERE
DIRECCIONES.ID_PERSONA = PERSONAS.ID
ORDER BY DIRECCIONES.TIPO_DIRECCION ASC
```

Comment: DIRECCIONES.TIPO_DIRECCION OVER (PARTITION BY DIRECCIONES.ID_PERSONA)

Me aparece un error, como si la sintaxis no fuera la correcta. Pero es por ahí por donde "van los tiros".